Using Type1 fonts with luatex
How do I force luatex to load Type1 fonts instead of OpenType fonts?
Explanation: I'm writing some tests, and I try to
compare the PDFs by rendering them at 300 dpi and then
comparing them pixel by pixel. Unfortunately the difference
between pdftex (type1) and luatex (opentype) is sometimes
huge. By using exactly the same font files I hope to reduce
the number of different pixels. Though I'm afraid that I
might be comparing rounding errors.
This is my test file:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{document}


if you use \usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} lualatex will use the type1 font. But e.g. ß will be wrong.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks. This greatly reduces the number of differences.

If you happen to have ConTeXt installed as well, you can overlay pdfs with context --extra=compare file1.pdf file2.pdf. That will give you a file context-extra.pdf in the same folder with the two pdf files, one in each layer. We use it all the time to track changes.

@mickep Thanks. That was new to me. But anyway it's a visual test and I was looking for automated testing. But comparing PDFs might be the wrong way to go. I guess I will continue with l3build and use visual tools only if a test fails.
